# Can I use meet for an online meeting?

Tags: american-english, formality, email

I would like to know if I can say "We can meet on Monday or Tuesday" in email as a reply to a sales person's email asking for a couple of days options for an online meeting -- a sort of Skype call. I am asking if the word *meet* is appropriate here and I welcome suggestions for a better reply to this email.

Comment: Just call it a "Skype meeting" if you want to be specific. Or "Lync meeting" or "Webex" or ... whatever you use.

Comment: If you want to sound more formal, you could consider using **video conference**, **online conference**, **web conference**, **web meeting**...

Comment: One thing you could do is review the websites of WebEx, GoToMeeting, FreeConference, and other conference services and see what terminology *they* use.

Comment: We use WebCon, V-Con or Webex  to refer to online video conferences in our organization.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who you're talking to. Between friends, it's okay to use *meet*. At work, *meet* will be understood but will sound informal. I agree with previous comments. You can just use *video/online meeting/conference, Skype meeting*, etc.

I attend English class via Skype and we use: "Let's meet tomorrow" or "Are you available to Skype tomorrow?" These sound really informal. Just use what is appropriate for the situation and the person you are talking to.